# ngTable: customizing number of rows buttons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngtable

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/broapVsW9LVqguvcueA6?p=preview) I have a simple ngTable. I need to customize the buttons that allow the user to select the number of rows shown in the table. For example, if you click on "10" there's an inner shadow, I need to get rid of it. I see that it's a Bootstrap button but can't figure out how to change it. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in $data">
                <td title="'User ID'">{{ u.uid }}</td>
                <td title="'Name'">{{ u.nm }}</td>
                <td title="'Group'">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {

      $scope.data = [{
          uid: 'User 1',
          nm: 'Name 1',
          ugr: 'Group 1'
      }, {
          uid: 'User 2',
          nm: 'Name 2',
          ugr: 'Group 2'
      }];


      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
          count: 5
      }, {
          data: $scope.data
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css

```
    .btn-default:active, .btn-default.active {
         background : white !important;
     }
```